# Codeigniter clean data before storing it in a session

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am using Codeigniter in an app that grabs the data from an SQL server and display it. To save in performance I store the query results in the session for the user. The issue that I am having is that even when casting the query object as an array there are symbols and/or hidden characters on the data that will not allow me to store it in the session.

I manage to drill down the offending fields to 2 text fields and even when applying multiple filter like htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, trim, n2br, addslashes, etc there still seems to be other character that is damaging the session object.

What am I missing?

**Note:** if I remove the text fields from the query everything else is stored in the session without any problems. I am not storing the sessions on the database.

Comment: if you are not using database sessions then keep in mind it will save data in cookie and max limit of cookie to store data is 4kb and other data will be lost

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping those characters using the common function `html_escape($mixed)`. It escapes characters based on the charset you specify in your configuration. You can read more about it [in the user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/common_functions.html) or read the source ([Common.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/common_functions.html)); currently, at line 642.